# How are local notifications handled for an app executing in the background after calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler?

Tags: ios

If a local notification triggers while an app is executing in the 10 minute background window after calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:, then is the notification presented to the user or delivered to the app?